# How to do seat selection for interconnecting flights from Qatar and IndiGo?

Tags: check-in, seating, qatar-airways, indigo

I wasn't able to select seats for interconnecting flights with Qatar and IndiGo. I could for Qatar but the next flight with Indigo is not showing any results. Please suggest how to check in. Also explain so that I can generate a boarding pass.

Answer (score 3):

I just traveled on a Qatar Airways ticket and the Chennai-Doha leg was operated by Indigo. I was able to call Indigo while in Chennai, under 48 hours from departure, to do seat selection. The customer service rep I called stated that the department handling the seat assignment was busy and said they'll call me back on the number (Indian SIM) I called from. They called me back an hour later and helped me select seats and it worked out fine.

The boarding pass - I was only able to get at the airport, but they gave me boarded passes for the onward Qatar Airways flight too and the luggage was transferred directly.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, IME you can't select seats on IndiGo connections for Qatar flights. (That's not unusual for codeshare connections.) Just continue checking in without selecting a seat.